# Recycler view inside coordinator layout is not scrolling programmatically

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have following XML layout. I am using recycler inside Coordinator layout. Although when I scroll manually, it works as expected. But when I am calling 
`mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(selectedPosition);` or `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(selectedPosition);` to scroll the recycler view programmatically its not scrolling. Below is my XML code

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/backgroundBlue">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_layout_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_layout_margin"
                    app:cardElevation="@dimen/small_layout_margin"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/details"
                        layout="@layout/detail_layout" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_layout_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_layout_margin"
                    app:cardElevation="@dimen/small_layout_margin"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <include layout="@layout/store_layout" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_layout_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_layout_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

At particular instance, I want my particular item in the recycler view to be on top of screen. I have below java code,

```
if (selectedPosition != 0) {
                    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.tab_appbar);
                    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
                    if(behavior!=null) {
                        behavior.onNestedPreScroll(mCoordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, mRecyclerView, 0, (int) mRecyclerView.getY(), new int[]{0, 0});
                        mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(selectedPosition);
                        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(selectedPosition);
                    }
     }
```

any idea, how to pull an item of recycler view to the top of screen?

Comment: Any news about this post ?

Answer (score 0):

CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour is works with only NestedScroll event. When you try to scroll RecyclerView programmatically it is treat as normal scroll.

Write below line to inform RecyclerView start NesteadScroll, With **ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL** and **ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH**

**ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL:**  Indicates scrolling along the vertical axis. 
**ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH:** Indicates that the input type for the gesture is caused by something which is not a user touching a screen. This is usually from a fling which is settling.

```
recycler_view.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL, ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
recycler_view.smoothScrollBy(0,200)
```